# Create a sql file and download to custom folder

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i created a sql file using php and i need to download to my custom folder but i automatically download to "download" folder
i need to download to my custom folder

```
$directory = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/james/makent_learn/public/backup';

$full_path = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/james/makent_learn/public/backup/mybackup_1630250271.sql';


header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($full_path)."\""); 
readfile($full_path);
```

Comment: You cannot place a file on my system anywhere you want to. Think how useful that would be to a hacker. You can only specify a suggeted filename, but the user gets a dialog and can select location and name where ever they like

Comment: hi @RiggsFolly thank you for your response, i just need to place my file inside my htdocs folder

Comment: then use `file_put_contents()`